# Pandas 0.14.1: assign timestamps to columns fails

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Why does this works?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
grid = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
year_velocities = pd.DataFrame()
hours = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2010', periods=10, freq='H')
temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
for h in hours:
    print h
    temp_df = grid.copy()
    temp_df["time"] = h.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    year_velocities = year_velocities.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```

While if I replace

```
temp_df["time"] = h.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

with

```
temp_df["time"] = h
```

it fails?

I end up having an empty temp_df.

It seems that i cannot assign a TimeStamp to a column?

UPDATE: The code works in both cases. The issue appears when I try to visualize the value of temp_df and year_velocities with the Anaconda Spyder Variable Explorer.

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aerg01341\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dicteditor.py", line 411, in createEditor
    if not editor.setup_and_check(value):
  File "C:\Users\aerg01341\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dataframeeditor.py", line 409, in setup_and_check
    self.dataModel = DataFrameModel(data, parent=self)
  File "C:\Users\aerg01341\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dataframeeditor.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.max_min_col_update()
  File "C:\Users\aerg01341\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\dataframeeditor.py", line 90, in max_min_col_update
    df_abs = self.df[self.complex_intran].abs()
  File "C:\Users\aerg01341\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3662, in abs
    return np.abs(self)
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NaTType'
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What is the error you get?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I have replaced the code with a working one.

Comment: Then I think you should report that to Spyder: https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/list